# Is the iframe the right thing to use here? If so, how to make it clickable?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to display a dynamic iframe on my site and I need to make the entire pic be a clickable link to the original page. Which is here:
http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/radar.php?rid=okx&product=N0R&loop=yes

```css
iframe {
  -moz-transform: scale(01.2, 01.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(01.2, 01.2);
  -o-transform: scale(01.2, 01.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(01.2, 01.2);
  transform: scale(01.2, 01.2);
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

iframe-link1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:inline-block;
  width:90px;
  height:60px;
  z-index:5;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-link1">

  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/northeast_loop.php" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -537px; height: 700px; margin-top: -520px; width: 590px;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <a href="http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/radar.php?rid=okx&product=N0R&loop=yes"></a>

</div>
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible.

FYI, I have permission to use the other site.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hi Kuzgun.  I am trying to make the iframe a link to that page, not just a frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways, one is to create an a tag which will overlap the iframe.

Another way is to use javascript, this is more elegant.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("your_iframe_id").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  window.location.href = 'http://newurl.com';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think that won't work because of same origin policy. Also note you can use `contentDocument` instead of `contentWindow.document`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with javascript.  is this correct? 
'<script>
document.getElementById("radar").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  window.location.href = 'http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/radar.php?rid=okx&product=N0R&loop=yes';
}
</script>
    
<div id="radar"style="overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/northeast_loop.php" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -537px; height: 700px; margin-top: -520px; width: 590px;"></iframe>
    </div>'

Comment: @JPRukus75 You must use `document.getElementById("radar")` after `<div id="radar">`.

Comment: @Oriol and Kuzgun.  Thank you for all your help.  I have it working with some styling issues to resolve.  Have a great day and thanks for your help again.